# How can I make a request followed by an array of requests from that response?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am making a request to a server to get a list of items.

For simplicity sake, lets say the first API request returns a list of Pokemon.

getPokemon()

```
"objects" :[
 { "name": "Bulbasaur", "id": "1234"}, 
 { "name": "Squirtle", "id": "4321" },
 ...
]
```

What I need to do is, for each of those Pokemon returned, I need to make a separate request for more details about the Pokemon using the id.

getPokemonDetails(`id: "1234"`)

```
"data" : { 
   "age": "12", 
   "height": "2 feet", 
    ... }
```

Picture I am trying to make a list of all the Pokemon heights. I need details from each separate request, after the parent getPokemon request is made.

Each request returns a promise.

Something I have tried but does not work:

```
this.provider.getPokemon().then(results => {
   foreach pokemon in results {
       this.provider.getPokemonDetails(pokemon.id).then(detail => {
           myData.push(detail.height)
       })
   }
})
```

It seems that there is an issue with the timing of this.

How can I do this in Ionic 3?

A few things that seem to jump out at me: `forkJoin, map, mergeMap`... what is it I am looking for?

Comment: Please clarify: are your API requests actually set up as promises or observables? Your examples appear to suggest promises, but you ask about methods which are specific to observables.

Comment: @miqh they are set up as promises. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.provider.getPokemon().then(results => {
     results.map(pokemon => {
         this.provider.getPokemonDetails(pokemon.id).then(detail => {
              myData.push(detail.height);
         });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin to combine multiple http sent requests. Let me show an example:

```
this.provider.getPokemon().flatMap(results => {
   const ids = results.objects.map(result => result.id)
   const observables = ids.forEach(id => this.provider.getPokemonDetails(id))
   return forkJoin(observables)
}).subscribe(result => console.log(result);
```

[Stackblitz with similar use case this also contains promise example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmwvuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)